# Coloring Rarefaction curve lines by metadata (vegan package) (phyloseq package)

Tags: r, vegan, phyloseq

First time question asker here. I wasn't able to find an answer to this question in other posts (love stackexchange, btw).

Anyway...
I'm creating a rarefaction curve via the vegan package and I'm getting a very messy plot that has a very thick black bar at the bottom of the plot which is obscuring some low diversity sample lines.
Ideally, I would like to generate a plot with all of my lines (169; I could reduce this to 144) but make a composite graph, coloring by Sample Year and making different types of lines for each Pond (i.e: 2 sample years: 2016, 2017 and 3 ponds: 1,2,5). I've used phyloseq to create an object with all my data, then separated my OTU abundance table from my metadata into distinct objects (jt = OTU table and sampledata = metadata). My current code:

```
 jt <- as.data.frame(t(j)) # transform it to make it compatible with the proceeding commands
rarecurve(jt
          , step = 100
          , sample = 6000
          , main = "Alpha Rarefaction Curve"
          , cex = 0.2
          , color = sampledata$PondYear)

# A very small subset of the sample metadata
                  Pond    Year
F16.5.d.1.1.R2     5      2016
F17.1.D.6.1.R1     1      2017
F16.1.D15.1.R3     1      2016
F17.2.D00.1.R2     2      2017
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhuDc.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to plot a rarefaction curve with ggplot. I used data available in the [phyloseq](http://joey711.github.io/phyloseq-demo/phyloseq-demo.html) package available from bioconductor.

to install phyloseq:

```
source('http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R')
biocLite('phyloseq')
library(phyloseq)
```

other libraries needed

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vegan)
```

data:

```
mothlist <- system.file("extdata", "esophagus.fn.list.gz", package = "phyloseq")
mothgroup <- system.file("extdata", "esophagus.good.groups.gz", package = "phyloseq")
mothtree <- system.file("extdata", "esophagus.tree.gz", package = "phyloseq")
cutoff <- "0.10"
esophman <- import_mothur(mothlist, mothgroup, mothtree, cutoff)
```

extract OTU table, transpose and convert to data frame

```
otu <- otu_table(esophman)
otu <- as.data.frame(t(otu))
sample_names <- rownames(otu)

out <- rarecurve(otu, step = 5, sample = 6000, label = T)
```

Now you have a list each element corresponds to one sample:

Clean the list up a bit:

```
rare <- lapply(out, function(x){
  b <- as.data.frame(x)
  b <- data.frame(OTU = b[,1], raw.read = rownames(b))
  b$raw.read <- as.numeric(gsub("N", "",  b$raw.read))
  return(b)
})
```

label list

```
names(rare) <- sample_names
```

convert to data frame:

```
rare <- map_dfr(rare, function(x){
  z <- data.frame(x)
  return(z)
}, .id = "sample")
```

Lets see how it looks:

```
head(rare)
  sample       OTU raw.read
1      B  1.000000        1
2      B  5.977595        6
3      B 10.919090       11
4      B 15.826125       16
5      B 20.700279       21
6      B 25.543070       26
```

plot with ggplot2

```
ggplot(data = rare)+
  geom_line(aes(x = raw.read, y = OTU, color = sample))+
  scale_x_continuous(labels =  scales::scientific_format())
```

[image]

vegan plot:

```
rarecurve(otu, step = 5, sample = 6000, label = T) #low step size because of low abundance
```

[image]

One can make an additional column of groupings and color according to that.

Here is an example how to add another grouping. Lets assume you have a table of the form:

```
groupings <- data.frame(sample = c("B", "C", "D"),
                       location = c("one", "one", "two"), stringsAsFactors = F)
groupings
  sample location
1      B      one
2      C      one
3      D      two
```

where samples are grouped according to another feature. You could use `lapply` or `map_dfr` to go over `groupings$sample` and label `rare$location`.

```
rare <- map_dfr(groupings$sample, function(x){ #loop over samples
  z <- rare[rare$sample == x,] #subset rare according to sample 
  loc <- groupings$location[groupings$sample == x] #subset groupings according to sample, if more than one grouping repeat for all
  z <- data.frame(z, loc) #make a new data frame with the subsets
  return(z)
})

head(rare)
  sample       OTU raw.read loc
1      B  1.000000        1 one
2      B  5.977595        6 one
3      B 10.919090       11 one
4      B 15.826125       16 one
5      B 20.700279       21 one
6      B 25.543070       26 one
```

Lets make a decent plot out of this

```
ggplot(data = rare)+
  geom_line(aes(x = raw.read, y = OTU, group = sample, color = loc))+
  geom_text(data = rare %>% #here we need coordinates of the labels
              group_by(sample) %>% #first group by samples
              summarise(max_OTU = max(OTU), #find max OTU
                        max_raw = max(raw.read)), #find max raw read
              aes(x = max_raw, y = max_OTU, label = sample), check_overlap = T, hjust = 0)+
  scale_x_continuous(labels =  scales::scientific_format())+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! That was tricky! Now I understand why people think R is painful to use. Isn't there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: @Jari Oksanen: `rerecurve` function from `vegan` has arguments for `col` and `lty` one could specify those and manually add a legend if `ggplot` is not intended.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question but I originally came here for the same reason and along the way found out that in a recent (2021) update `vegan` has made this a LOT easier.

This is an absolutely bare-bones example.

Ultimately we're going to be plotting the final result in ggplot so you'll have full customization options, and this is a tidyverse solution with dplyr.

```
library(vegan)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

I'm going to use the dune data within `vegan` and generate a column of random metadata for the site.

```
data(dune)

metadata <- data.frame("Site" = as.factor(1:20),
                       "Vegetation" = rep(c("Cactus", "None")))
```

Now we will run `rarecurve`, but provide the argument `tidy = TRUE` which will export a dataframe rather than a plot.

One thing to note here is that I have also used the `step` argument. The default step is 1, and this means by default you will get one row per individual per sample in your dataset, which can make the resulting dataframe huge. Step = 1 for `dune` gave me over 600 rows. Reducing the step too much will make your curves blocky, so it will be a balance between step and resolution for a nice plot.

Then I piped a left join right into the `rarecurve` call

```
dune_rare <- rarecurve(dune,
                       step = 2,
                       tidy = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(metadata)
```

Now it will be plottable in ggplot, with a color/colour call to whatever metadata you attached.
From here you can customize other aspects of the plot as well.

```
ggplot(dune_rare) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Sample, y = Species, group = Site, colour = Vegetation)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[dune-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPvRr.png)

(Sorry it says I'm not allowed to embed the image yet :( )